# Update a table after comparing 2 mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables name master and client
my master table looks like:

```
+-----------+---------+--------+--------+--------+-----------------+------------+---------+
| name      | mall_id | type   | start  | end    | 1_start | 1_end | item_count | Task_id |
+-----------+---------+--------+--------+--------+-----------------+------------+---------+
| Straight6 |    7    | A      |  561   |  728   |    NULL |  NULL |         1  |       1 |
| Straight6 |    7    | A      |  19    |  97    |    NULL |  NULL |         1  |       1 |
| Straight8 |    7    | B      | 58     | 100    |    NULL |  NULL |         2  |       1 |
| Straight9 |    7    | B      | 51     | 110    |    NULL |  NULL |         3  |       1 |
+-----------+---------+--------+--------+--------+-----------------+------------+---------+
```

my client table looks like:

```
+-----------+-------+----+------+-------+-------+---------+------+
| name      | item  | id |train | start | end   | pick_id | type |
+-----------+-------+----+------+-------+-------+---------+------+
| Straight6 |     1 |  1 |  4   |   561 | 080   |    7    | A    |
| Straight6 |     2 |  1 |  5   |   561 | 610   |    7    | A    |
| Straight6 |     3 |  2 |  4   |   311 | 431   |    7    | A    |
| Straight8 |     1 |  1 |  5   |   561 | 610   |    7    | A    |
| Straight8 |     3 |  2 |  4   |   311 | 431   |    7    | A    |
| Straight9 |     6 |  2 |  4   |   311 | 431   |    7    | A    |
| Straight9 |     3 |  2 |  4   |   311 | 431   |    7    | A    |
+-----------+-------+----+------+-------+-------+---------+------+
```

I want to compare item_count of master table and item value in client table to **make changes in client table**

The change that I want to do is :

When item_count =1 in master table and item >1 in client table , then I wish to replace all these entries in client table having item>1 to item =1

(so for eg: here i will replace 2 entries in client table who have item>1)

So I used this query to find the entries:

Code:

```
select distinct m.name, item_count, item 
from master m 
join client p 
on m.name=p.name 
where item_count = 1 and item > 1;
```

But how should I update them?

Update  table client Set item =1  where m.name=p.name and item_count=1 AND item>1;

Is this wrong?

Comment: You are referencing another table, so you need to specify that table even though you're not changing anything in it: `UPDATE client c, master m SET...`

Comment: I did  "UPDATE client c, master m SET item =1  where item_count = 1 and item > 1; "                                                                                                                                          However it changed many more entries which didnt quite belong to this category. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: What happened to `m.name=p.name`?

Comment: UPDATE client c, master m SET item =1 where  m.name = p.name AND item_count = 1 and item > 1;                                                                                                                       Is this what you are suggesting?